# Virtual machine without Internet

Tags: networking, virtualbox, kubuntu, internet, nat

I have a VirtualBox machine with Kubuntu and I lost Internet suddenly two days ago.   I didn't do anything but uninstalling Python which I suppose it's not related to a network connection.

I tried everything but the only I've achieved is to turn the red wifi applet into blue but it doesn't work. I did this:

```
sudo ip link set enp0s3 on
```

I use a NAT connection.

Comment: Python is used for all kind of system scripts, so probably you have crippled your Ubuntu by uninstalling python.

Comment: Is there any solution in that case?

Comment: Install a new VM is probably the easiest way. You could try to reinstall python, but apt and other utilities is broken too.

Comment: Is it possible that the USB detection is also affected?